# Pointer of a singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, pointers, linked-list

When appending an item to a singly linked list, the typical steps are:

1. create a new node `y`
2. copy `list.head` in `y` (`y=list.head`)
3. slide all the nodes until we find the next field of `y` is `NULL` (`y=y.next`)
4. add the node (`y.next=newNode`)

Now I ask myself: if I do `y = list.head`, `y` and `list.head` essentially have two different memory locations, right? If I do now `y.next = newNode`, now the next field `list.head` changed (in `newNode`)? If so, why? Are `y` and `list.head` not two different objects? I am probably confusing me with the pointers...

Comment: In which language? when you say `have two different memory` it depends.

Comment: @AmiHollander Now it shouldd be more readable..thanks to Vincent_van_der_Weele

Comment: @m_callens I know how linked lists work, it's clear on my mind.. it's not clear at the "memory locations level"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `singly linked list`, each `node` typically has the attributes/values:

- data
- next

When you set a `pointer` to the `head` of the entire `linked list`, that `pointer` holds the *exact same* memory location as the `pointer` for the `head` which *should* be the first `node`.

When you set a `node's` `next` value, you are adding a new `node's` memory location to the tail of the `linked list`.

Answer (score 0):

(lets assume you that you are not talking about a specific programming language)

If you create new node `y` and point it to `list.head` they will point to the same memory location.

But, when you say you copy `list.head` to `y` it depends if you are DeepCopy or ShallowCopy the list to `y`.
It's seems like you did `y = list.head` and thats make sense that the `list` changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are appending to the head of the list, you want your new node **y** to be in front.

1. Create new node **y** (and set any data)
2. **y.next = list.head** (imagine putting **y** in front of the list)
3. **list.head = y** (recognize **y** as the new start of the list)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the case : I want append a new node in the queue of the list... when I do y=y.next to scan the list , does y change only his status or it begins a copy of the y.next node?

Comment: when you do `y = y.next` you just point y to be y.next, hence no new memory is located.